# Same Origin Policy for supporting between http and https

Tags: wcf, jquery, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am using JQuery Ajax to request for an API using POST method.

My pages are going to be viewed on mobile hence we are keeping them very light and also using http as the protocol.
Few of our APIs passes tokens which would need to be secured, hence we were planning to use https protocol.

We have exposed both the endpoints http and https on our WCF Service. Also, have made sure to allow cross scripting by adding the following config in our web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

At the WCF Operation contract, I have checked for OPTIONS header to return by setting the 
above headers. Request never reaches the WCF operation. The browser itself stops the request as Same Origin policy.

I have observed getJSON works, but there were few limitations like it does'nt allow POST method and also complex objects to be passed.

What surprises me is that I have seen implementations where this is being allowed. Below is an example of what works in cross scripting.

Ex:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
console.log("in on success");
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
url: closure_compiler_service,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: 'js_code=' + $("#eval").val() + "&output_info=compiled_code&output_format=json&compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY&formatting=pretty_print",
success: function (jscode) {
//do something...
},
error: function () {
console.log("Error from Closure compile");
},
async: false
});
}
```

Am I missing any thing to workaround the Same origin policy.

Comment: Can you use a packet sniffer like WireShark to analyze the actual network traffic? It would be helpful to see the actual requests/responses being made by the browser. The request could be rejected at the preflight stage, which would make an actual HTTP OPTIONS request to your server. 

My first guess is that '*' is not a valid value for Access-Control-Allow-Headers. According to the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), the header value must be a comma-delimited list of accepted headers. 

Also, can you post the snippet of code that is not working?